# Escaping = in a sql connection string

Tags: sql-server, connection

I have a SQL Server 2016 connection string like the following:

`<instance name="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=database1;Initial Catalog=Nis_Dashboard;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mysqlacct;Password=cPrVRY=whYix;" />`

My issue is that (as you can see above), there is a '=' in the password. I believe this is causing connection string to break. Is there a way that I can escape the '='? I tried using '==' and '\=' but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Try enclosing the value in quotes.

Comment: I tried both cPrVRY'='whYix and cPrVRY""=""whYix (I had to use two double quotes, because the whole Connection String is also in quotes) but didn't seem to work :(

Comment: Don't escape the equal, enclose the entire value like `'cPrVRY=whYix'`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this doesn't seem to work either :(

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? SqlClient seems to accept the password with the equal sign with or without quotes on my system.

Comment: The error is "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Here is the current xml blurb that I have in my xml file. I read this with C# and use SqlConnection class.

`<instance name="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=database1;Initial Catalog=Nis_Dashboard;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mysqlacct;Password='cPrVRY=whYix';" />`

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to your question? This looks like an error that would be returned if you tried to execute the connection string as a query.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and tip. We pass the connection string to an in-house tool which manages the connection. The single quotes worked when I removed a key-value pair from the connection string which I thought was required by the in-house tool (but seems to be required only for Integrated security) Once I removed that, things worked.